# gsutil-serviceexception-401-anonymous-caller-does-not-have-storage-objects-list for kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, gsutil

I am using google kubernetes engine and have configured workload identity for communication between containers and google apis

I am getting 401 anonymous caller error when I try to use gsutil command( have installed only gsutil command)

Whereas python application uses library to communicate with storage pubsub etc.. and it is working fine.

Is there any way to authorize the gsutil command with kubernetes service account(workload identity is used) ?

Comment: Please check which account you're using with a command `gcloud config list` and update your question. You can use this command [`gcloud auth activate-service-account`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account) to "authorize access to Google Cloud Platform with a service account".

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Workload Identity but `gsutil` and `gcloud` are co-dependent. Without `gcloud` to manage credentials, you'd need to configure ,`gsutil` directly: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/config#configuring-service-account-credentials But this may not work with Workload Identity

Comment: I read up on [Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity). Because Workload Identity authenticates the Pod as the Service Account, your Python app (using Application Default Credentials) will use the Pod's identity and this explains why it works. But, you need to pass the Pod's identity to `gsutil`. The test in step #8 uses `gcloud` and so the approach presumably mounts the credentials where `gcloud` expects them. If you analyze how #8 works, you should be able to get `gsutil` working

Comment: Hi @DazWilkin currently we do not have gcloud installed on the container. Will try to add gcloud as well and see.